# decompress Gzip sqlite database in android

Tags: android

I'm android developer.
I have a  `Gzip` file that contains bunch of 'sqlite' database.how can I decompress and save it in Android.

Answer (score 3):

```
private byte[] readFromZip(InputStream is) {
    try {
        GZIPInputStream gzip = new GZIPInputStream(is);
        byte[] buff = new byte[2048];
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        int len;
        while ((len = gzip.read(buff)) != 0) {
            baos.write(buff, 0, len);
        }
        return baos.toByteArray();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

1. Use [GZIPInputStream](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/zip/GZIPInputStream.html) to read your gzip file. and output the file to your sdcard or internal storage.
2. Use [SQLiteOpenHelper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html) to open the database.

Comment: I use 'GZIPInputStream' but I get the Unknown format (magic number 4b50)

Comment: So Your file is not compressed by gzip.

Comment: Can U explain for me: *read the 'GZIP' file whit 'GZIPInputStream' *and save the files individually. with an example.
Thanks a lot.